# Why is my table content blank and couldn't set data?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am to learn [model/view](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) and write a demo, but my table has no data and couldn't set data.
And `checkIndex` method of `QAbstractItemMode` couldn't work ???

The code:

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *
from PyQt5.QtChart import *
import numpy as np

class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data: np.ndarray):
        super().__init__()
        self.dataArray = data

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return self.dataArray.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return self.dataArray.shape[1]

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role=None):
        # checkIndex method not working ???
        # self.checkIndex(index, QAbstractItemModel::IndexIsValid)

        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        if index.row() >= self.dataArray.shape[0] or index.column() >= self.dataArray.shape[1]:
            return None

        if role in [Qt.DisplayRole, Qt.EditRole]:
            return self.dataArray[index.row()][index.column()]
        else:
            return None

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=None):
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None

        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return f'Column {section}'
        else:
            return f'Row {section}'

    def flags(self, index: QModelIndex):
        if not index.isValid():
            return Qt.ItemIsEnabled

        return super().flags(index) | Qt.ItemIsEditable


    def setData(self, index: QModelIndex, value, role=None):
        if index.isValid() and role == Qt.EditRole:
            self.dataArray[index.row()][index.column()] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [role])

            return True

        return False


class DemoA(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        data = np.random.randint(1, 100, (4, 6))
        model = TableModel(data)

        # delegate = ComboBoxDelegate()

        table = QTableView()
        table.setModel(model)
        # table.setItemDelegate(delegate)

        self.setCentralWidget(table)

app = QApplication([])
demo = DemoA()
demo.show()
app.exec()
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyQt5 does not handle numpy data types so it will not display them. In your case, the data stored in the numpy array is numpy.int64, so the solution is to convert it to an integer or float:

```py
if role in [Qt.DisplayRole, Qt.EditRole]:
    return int(self.dataArray[index.row()][index.column()])
```